# Determine the index for when a sum of numbers greater than another number

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, search

I have this function which is supposed to tell the index of where the sum of a list of numbers becomes equal or more than a series of numbers. I have done this implementation to check the index but it is too slow for number of items in the list is greater than 1,000,000. How can I get it to improve on speed? I heard that I could use `bisect.bisect_left` but I am not sure.

`n` is basically the number of element in `v` which is is the list of elements to be summed which I am trying the find the index of. `noq` is the number of elements in `vom` which is what I am summing against.

Example for `[8 3 10 22 1]` and `20` ... the index at which the list becomes greater than or equal to 20 is 3

```
import math
import os
import random
import re
import sys

import math 

def bossBusiness (n, v, noq, vom):

    adder = 0
    indicies = []
    count = 1

    for i in vom:

        for t in v:
            if (sum(v) < i):
                indicies.append(-1)
                break

            adder = adder + t 
            if (adder >= i):
                indicies.append(count)
                count = 1
                adder = 0
                break
            else:
                count = count + 1

    for i in indicies:

        fptr.write(str(i) + '\n')
```

Comment: what are each of the variables (n, v, noq, vom)? and can the series of numbers be sorted?

Comment: n is basically the number of element in v which is is the list of elements to be summed which I am trying the find the index of. noq is the number of elements in vom which is what I am summing against. The list cannot be sorted. It has to preserve the other in which the elements come.

Comment: if noq cant be sorted, sum all your sub lists, create a dictionary with sum as key and index in list as value, and another sorted list of all sums, now go over the noq, if it is in the dict, found the index, if not see where it fits in the sorted list of sums, take the closest bigger value and take its index from the dict

Comment: Okay. I am going to see what I can do.

Comment: How would I check where it fits in the sorted list and take the closer bigger value and take its index?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compute the prefix sums, so your `[8, 3, 10, 22, 1]` becomes `[8, 11, 21, 43, 44]`, and then use binary search (for example with `bisect` as you mentioned).

Comment: Thank you. Can you explain how to use the bisect. I am not familiar with its use.

Comment: @NicoleFoster https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/bisect.html

Comment: okay but if I use that, wouldn't I be searching for 21 and not 22 and it wouldn't then find it?

Comment: @NicoleFoster You can use it to find the proper place for *any* number.

Comment: Okay. going to try. Thanks

Comment: I posted a second solution but it is still slow. Please have a look at it and see if I did as you said.

Comment: The new solution is down below.